# Finding value of definite integral - $f(f(x)) = x$

Tags: integration, functions, definite-integrals

**Question:**

> If $f(x)$ is such a function so that $f(f(x)) = x$ and $f(0) = 1$ then find the value of:
>   $$ \int_0^1(x+f(x))^{2016}dx$$

I have no clue where to start this question. A small hint would be appreciated.

Comment: @KennyLau Same exam xD He beat me to it by an hour.